# Read file in scala using buffer Reader

Tags: scala, bufferedreader

I have an input file in a temporary directory

I have to read the file and take the second line and then drop the first two word and save the String in a variable.
I am trying to read the file with bufferedReader and not fromSource.

The file is doc.txt and is as below

```
#doc source topic proportion ...
0 src/main/tempDir/new_corpus/0c3da178-2d99-453d-8d54-0ee4212f1ed8 186 0.005347593582886886 185 0.005347593582886886 184 0.005347593582886886 183 0.005347593582886886 182 0.005347593582886886 181 0.005347593582886886 180 0.005347593582886886 179 0.005347593582886886 178 0.005347593582886886 177 0.005347593582886886 176 0.005347593582886886 175 0.005347593582886886 174 0.005347593582886886 173 0.005347593582886886 172 0.005347593582886886 171
```

I have to read from "186 0.0053...."

The code i am using is

```
val in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/main/tempDir/doc.txt"))
val l: String = in.readLine()
```

but from here I am not able to get the desired result please suggest

Comment: What is wrong with [`Source`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/io/Source.html)?

Answer (score 1):

```
in.readLine                        //skip 1st line
val l: String = in.readLine()
                  .split("\\s+")  //split on whitespace
                  .drop(2)
                  .mkString(" ")  //restore whitespace
//l: String = 186 0.005347593582886886 185 0.00...
```